# Errors restoring a Sql Server 2008 database with Merge Replication

Tags: sql, sql-server, replication, database-restore

I'm trying to restore my database from a file and get the following error:

"An explicit DROP INDEX is not allowed on index..."
"It is being used for PRIMARY KEY constraint enforcement."

If I delete the primary key and create a new backup it restores fine.

Unique things about the primary key:
--It is on a GUID with default NEWSEQUENCIALID()
--It is used for merge replication

Some tables with identical primary key structures are restored just fine.  But there are 2 tables that result in the above error when I set the primary key.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a 4 months old anwer but somebody might find it useful.
I had the same issue restoring a .bak file of a database with merge replication, you need to go to options and check the "WITH KEEP_REPLICATION" option, then restore your database as usual. The restore process shall success.